# Bean validation not working. I'm using JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 3.3

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation

The validation works for the front end (jsf).  However, it is not getting validated on prepersist.  I'm setting manufacturer to null and it is getting stored in the database as such instead of throwing the constraint violation exception.  Thanks.

Here is the relevant part of my entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


/**
 * The persistent class for the CAR database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR")
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CAR_ID")
    private int carId;

    @Column(name="MANUFACTURER")
    @NotNull(message = "A manufacturer is required.")
    private String manufacturer;
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="src_persistence">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/BEAN_VALIDATION_DS</jta-data-source>
        <class>
            xxx.beanvalidation.persistence.Car
        </class>
        <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="callback"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Optimistic" value="false"/>
            <property name="openjpa.LockManager" value="none"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="dbo"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my DAO:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.westfieldgrp.beanvalidation.persistence.Car;
import com.westfieldgrp.beanvalidation.persistence.Driver;
import com.westfieldgrp.beanvalidation.persistence.Person;
import com.westfieldgrp.common.data.dao.DAOInterface;

public class CarDAO  {

    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public void save(Person convertedPerson, Driver convertedDriver, Car convertedCar) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        //convertedPerson.setName(convertedPerson.getName()); // To test JPA validation
        Person savedPerson =  em.merge(convertedPerson);
        convertedDriver.setPersonId(savedPerson.getPersonId());
        Driver savedDriver = em.merge(convertedDriver);
        convertedCar.setDriverId(savedDriver.getPersonId());
        if("test".equals(convertedCar.getManufacturer())){
            convertedCar.setManufacturer(null);// To test JPA validation
        }
        em.persist(convertedCar);
        em.flush();
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("src_persistence");
            entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried defining the column like so, @Column(name="MANUFACTURER", nullable = false)? Probably won't throw a constraint violation but it should throw and exception that you can catch and handle.

Comment: @ChadNC That does throw and exception, but I don't think that's the solution I'm looking for.  For example, could I apply this constraint @Size(min = 2, max = 14) using that approach?

Comment: Are you sure the event listeners fire? You could try to add a @PrePersist to your Entity. If this method gets called I would expect Bean Validation to occur as well.

Comment: Also have you tried using 'auto' as validation mode (even though 'callback' should work as well). Just trying to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Hardy Thanks for the input.  I will try those two things and report.  Do I need to do anything through settings/annotations to make the event listeners fire or should that happen automatically?  I'm not using any custom listeners.

Comment: @Hardy Changing it to AUTO had no effect.  I added a prepersist method with an out.print and that gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate 3.3 is NOT a JPA2.0 implementation. You need Hibernate >=3.5.1 for JPA2.0.
There is no integration of the bean-validation API in Hibernate 3.3

To integrate the bean-validation into hibernate 3.3 you have to implement an BeanValidationEventListener. See the Hibermate implementation as an example:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/beanvalidation/BeanValidationEventListener.java